# How to disturb a particle distribution

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, electrostatics, waves, experimental-physics

I have a set of N macroscopic particles, each representing a group of electrons. Each of these macroscopic particles has a different charge.

My system is one-dimensional so all particle´s positions are described by their position along the z-axis. I have an array `positions`of length N, where each element represents the z position of a single particle. `positions[i]` represents the position of the i$^{th}$ particle.

These values for the positions are such that the carge density is uniform along z between $0$ and $L$.
$$\rho_1(z) = N_1$$

I need to disturb my charge distribution by a factor:
$$\delta \rho = A \cos \left( \frac{\pi mz}{L} \right)$$
In order to have a final charge distribution of:
$$\rho_2(z) = N_1 + A \cos \left( \frac{\pi mz}{L} \right)$$
with $m$ an integer equal or larger to 1 in order to keep charge conserved.

I have been struggling with this for longer than I would like to admit, could someone point me into the right direction. How could I modify each `positions[i]` in order to modify my charge distribution as expected.

Effectively what I need is to remove particles from the region where $\delta \rho < 0$ and add them in regions where $\delta \rho > 0$ but following the cosine density I need.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that you want to keep the total charge constant. Let's assume that your array is of size $2m$. Then you can update the first $m$ entries of the array using the assignment $r[i] \leftarrow r[i] + A\cos(\pi i/m)$ and the last $m$ entries using the assignment $r[i] \leftarrow r[i] - A\cos(\pi i/m)$. I suggest that you modify each half separately to ensure that the total charge indeed remains constant.